# How to update ObservableCollection in codeBehind after drag and drop on listview - WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, drag-and-drop

I am having some difficulty when I use the Josh Smith's issue for DnD on listView.

I have an ObservableCollection of "DetailTable" that I initialize in the ViewModel when I create the view :

(ListeTables is CollectionViewSource where I initialize and use my data)

```
public ObservableCollection<DetailTable> ListeTablesDisplay
{
    get
    {
        var l = ListeTables.View.Cast<DetailTable>().ToList();
        return new ObservableCollection<DetailTable>(l);
    }
}
```

The listView in the Xaml file :

```
    <ListView Name="ListeViewTables" SelectionMode="Single" 
              AllowDrop="true"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ListeTablesDisplay, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTable, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              Margin="10,83,831,61">
```

And then I call the Class of Josh Smith for the DnD in the View CodeBehind :

```
public DataView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    new ListViewDragDropManager<DetailTable>(this.ListeViewTables);
}
```

Until now, the drag and drop work correctly, but in the ViewModel the order of items of the ObservableCollection is not coherent with what I do in the View.

Example : if I move the item-3 to the 5th position, it's ok with the View but when I debug I see the item-3 always to the 3rd position in my ObservableCollection.

It's very problematic for what I want to do, I hope someone can help me !

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the URL of the Class of Josh Smith?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yeah sure ! [Used by NuGet](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17266/Drag-and-Drop-Items-in-a-WPF-ListView)

Answer (score 1):

If a person has the same problem, just add the event `ProcessDrop` on `ListViewDragDropManager`

Then in the viewModel the event need to move manually the item index in the ObservableCollection

```
    public static void OnProcessDrop(object sender, ProcessDropEventArgs<T> e)
    {
        e.ItemsSource.Move(e.OldIndex, e.NewIndex);

        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
```

[Here an example by the autor of ListViewDragDropManager - "Custom drop logic" for help](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17266/Drag-and-Drop-Items-in-a-WPF-ListView)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to handle this in the general case. OP was able to get it to work as desired with Smith's code by handling Smith's `ProcessDrop` event.

In the drop handler, determine whether the target ListView's `ItemsSource` is null.

If you have an `ItemsSource`, cast it to `System.Collections.IList` and do the reordering operation *on the list*, not on `Items`. Forget `Items` in this branch. If the items source is an `ObservableCollection<T>`, the ordering in the ListView will update. If it isn't, that's not your problem. The consumer of your code who provided the wrong list type needs to post a question asking why WPF doesn't get change notifications from `List<T>` or `int[]` or `String` or whatever.

If you don't have an `ItemsSource`, you just have ListViewItems. Reorder `Items`. Easy.

I've never before seen [Josh Smith's code](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17266/Drag-and-Drop-Items-in-a-WPF-ListView), and he'd be the guy to talk to if you need updates. Personally, I use an Adorner rather than restyling the list control items, but you can make a case for either approach.

Comment: Nothing is null, and the `ItemsSource` is an `ObservableCollection<T>`, I see and use the listView correctly. I have some checkBox and TextBox in it and all is update, but not the order after the drag and drop.

Comment: @Furiks Are you asking a question, or are you telling me there's something about my answer that isn't clear to you?

Comment: I think I didn't understand

Comment: @Furiks Are you handling the ProcessDrop event of the `ListViewDragDropManager`?

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't understand its usefulness but now it work :)